# Can't skype for Ubuntu 12 work on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: skype

I've installed Ubuntu 14, but I can't install Skype as the required version of Ubuntu is 12!? Is there a way to run Skype on Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the fact that the download page at the Skype web site states Ubuntu 12.04? That's misleading. It works just as fine on 14.04.

Please note that it's more convenient to install Skype from the Canonical Partner repository in the Ubuntu archive. Just [activate Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html), and you'll find that Skype shows up in Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic.